# MVC Uploading,File Management

Tags: asp.net-mvc, upload

Using vs'12, internet Application Template, asp.net MVC4 C#  with Kendo UI and Razor Views

**In My Controller**

[image]

Curious on why it won't allow me to create a Folder, then why it won't let me save to anywhere but a "Server MapPath"

1. Why not?
2. Whats the workaround? / the Right way to manage Files ( documentation would suffice )
3. Why can you only upload 29 images at same time, yes `maxRequestLength="2097151"` is set *29 works fine and fast, 30 takes 5 minutes and displays "The connection was reset"*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you debugging the application with IIS? If yes then the default application pool will be used and it will not have full permission to manage file system on desired location. The better way you should create app-pool with account to whom you can provide appropriate file management permission.

Comment: ,Attempting the ISS Solution now,  any idea on question 3?

Comment: Hmm don't have concrete answer on q#3 but .......max tequest length can be increased if your request content size is big. Regards to the connection was reset I believe it's happening from browser are you using FireFox?

Comment: Actually i found that the `maxRequestLength="1048576"` and `<requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="1073741824"/>` must match. Error Throwing Solved, this also solved the 29 images issue. As for the first issue i was using `http://www.iis.net/learn/manage/configuring-security/application-pool-identities` to try and fix the server issues, about to run and test.

Comment: I have found sofar that `~/App_Data` Folder doesnt exist on the server after re-publishing. When i did place it there i found that i didn't have permission. Now with the link in the prior comment that doesnt make sese. Especially not having Root access? Ideas?

Comment: Yes it's tire, access permission is required if you want manage files in folders, server.map path will help to do rest if the adrress.

Comment: Thanks there any documentation on how to do this server wise ? - if this is unrelated to the question  i can find it elsewhere, any links would help also. thanks. ( PN: I've tried the regular right click folderpermissions from the folder that contains the website, and Appool Permissions of IIS 7.5)

Comment: So i'm still looking at the rights.On a related note, there any reason why this won't work on the dev machine? my IIS should always have rights. Also i changed folders from App_DATA to UploadedImages and the "Viewing" Of the Images works great now, didn't like something about APP_DATA. Can this have anything to do with me not being able to create dir's on the dev machine?

Comment: I don't have any documentation which I can share it with you but this is the common practice for development I have been putting :).

Comment: Dev.Machine , you are terming it as your development machine where VS.Net Exists right? If Yes, then I would suggest you follow the same approach of debugging application from IIS during your development, in that sense it will make realistic environment which is your final deployment environment.

From VS.Net MVC Web Project->Properties->Web->Servers[Use Local IIS Web Server], also do not forget to create app pool with identity to which you can provide permission, use that app pool to run your application.

I hope now everything answers your questions.

Comment: Yes very clear! thank you, i was unsure weather or not to install some of the server tools - to change the app pool on the dev machine, so thanks.